Why does my sink disposal run with the wall switch in the off position?
I have a dishwasher and disposal on one breaker. The dishwasher stopped working and started flashing a maintenance light a few weeks ago. I have been doing dishes by hand.
Separately, I was using the disposal and it blew a fuse. I turned a screw on the bottom of the disposal to release any clogs and flipped the breaker. The disposal worked fine after I flipped the breaker to on again, and so because I was done with the disposal I turned off the light switch that turns off the disposal. However, then the disposal started running again with the switch in the off position. To turn off the disposal, I had to flip the breaker to the off position. When I flipped the breaker to on again, the disposal turned on even if the light switch is in the off position. So it is as if the light switch has somehow been reversed where off (on the light switch) means on.
My questions are:

What might be causing this?
Is there a deeper electrical issue that may explain the disposal and dishwasher problem?
Is there an immediate safety issue?

I plan to have an electrician come out soon.

You didn't explain how you repaired the fuse. Is that relevant?

I've read your post multiple times and seem to come to a different understanding each time. Does the disposal run with the wall switch in either position, or just when off? Did you do any work to it? Is it by chance a three-way setup?

1 - Is "fuse" here just another name for "breaker"? Or is there a fuse in the disposal itself? 2 - Not clear whether the disposal wall switch is now "reversed" or "not functioning at all and the disposal runs constantly if the breaker is turned on" - which are two very different situations. Please clarify.

So the disposal is wired up to the light switch? does the disposal now turn off when the light on? when you say it blew a fuse - do you mean it tripped breaker, or an actual fuse blew, and needed replacing - did you replace this yourself?

Are there two outlets under the sink: one for the dishwasher and one switched for the disposal?  Did you mix them up when plugging everything back in?

Your explanation is unclear. I am assuming that the disposal operates in either position of the switch. If so, than it is clear that the switch is defective. I find it hard to believe that the disposal operates in the off position of the switch and turns off in the on position of the switch. However, this would also indicate a defective switch Before calling in the electrician, replace the switch.

Did you dismount the switch from the wall?
If so, I would assume you simply reinstalled it upside down.
Unless you are saying that the unit runs no matter which position the switch is in, in which case you miswired and effectively bypassed the switch.
Hard to be certain without seeing it. Clearer descriptions and photos of the wiring would help.

It sounds as-if the switch is now defective,  if you are not confident to investigate inside the junction box behind the switch yourself then having an electrician investigate is a good move.
If the switch is getting hot, or making noises, lights, or smells (when the breaker is on) then yes there is danger. but leaving the breaker off makes it safe.
